# Returning extra fields with generatetreelist

Tags: cakephp

I don't know if I'm going the right way with the tree behavior but I'm trying to build a comment system for a blog. I would like to have an indentation of 5 level depth.

The generatetreelist method looks like it would be the fastest way to accomplish this but it doesn't look like you can add fields to the query. Am I right ? Is there a way to modify the method ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it for categories. You could modify accordingly.

In controller:

```
$categories = $this->Category->generatetreelist(null,null,null,"|-- ");
    $categories_array = array();
    foreach($categories as $k => $v)
    {
        $categories_array[$k] = $this->Category->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Category.id' => $k)));
        $categories_array[$k]["Category"]["path"] = $v;
    }

    $this->set(compact('categories','categories_array'));
```

In view:

```
    <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><?php __('Id');?></th>
        <th><?php __('Name');?></th>
        <th><?php __('Status');?></th>
        <th><?php __('Action');?></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($categories_array AS $categoryId => $category):
    $class = 'even';
    if ($i++ % 2 == 0) {
        $class = 'odd';
    }?>
    <tr class="<?php echo $class;?>">
    <td><?php echo $category['Category']['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $category["Category"]["path"];?></td>


    <?php if ($category['Category']['status'] == '1'){
    $published = 'Active';
        }else {
    $published = 'Inactive';
    } ?>
<td><?php echo $published;?></td>
<td>
 <?php echo $html->link($html->image("icons/16_icon_view.png"), array('action' => 'view', $category['Category']['id']), array('title'=>'View','escape' => false));?>&nbsp;
            <?php echo $html->link($html->image("icons/16_icon_edit.png"), array('action' => 'edit', $category['Category']['id']), array('title'=>'Edit','escape' => false));?>&nbsp;
            <?php echo $html->link($html->image("icons/16_icon_delete.png"), array('action' => 'delete', $category['Category']['id']), array('class'=>'delete_trigger','rel'=>'#error','title'=>'Delete','escape' => false));?>
        </td>
    </tr>

  <?php endforeach; ?>


</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it was me, I would just do this in the result set. As you get a numeric array in the first dimension of the results you could use that when outputting the data to indent or add a class to your comments as you needed.

Comment: Not sure I understand. You would not use the tree behavior? Or only the Article has many ArticleComment relationship.